# Angular 8 , ng2-cookie not getting delete after page reload

Tags: angular, cookies, angular8

i am developing an angular8 application. In which i have stored access_token ad refresh_token in Cookie.
When i login into application it get set with expiration time. On clicking logout its also get sd delted, using Cookie.delete().

But, let say i am on a route and just reload the page from browser button, app gets reload correctly but, now when i click logout, my Cookie is not getting deleted. (I have also tried ngx-cookie-service also) same behaviour in both. Upon page reload cookies not getting deleted.

```
public logout() {
    this.loginService.logout().subscribe(
      response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.loginService.removeCookie();
          this.loginService.authorities = [];
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
      },
      error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.loginService.removeCookie();
          this.loginService.authorities = [];
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
      );
  }

LoginService 
   removeCookie() {
        Cookie.delete('access_token');
        Cookie.delete('refresh_token');
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that you are calling the right method? I mean is it this.loginService.removeCookie(); or is it just this.removeCookie();

Comment: @ImmadHamid actually i just wrote method here, but yes i am calling this.loginService.removeCookie(); removecookie is in my loginservice.

Comment: what i did "Cookie.set('access_token', '', -1 , '/' );
        Cookie.set('refresh_token', '', -1 , '/' );" this is working in both scenario for me. normal logout and when i click logout after tab reload. But dont know if its right way or not.., As far what i have seen is if we have added some cookie before page reload, so after page reload its kinda break its relation for just delete operation, although value is geting from get method. so when we reset it with expire -1 it gets deleted

Answer (score 0):

Check the root path of the cookie in the browser inspector.
Mention the path such as

```js
Cookie.delete('access_token','/app/name');
Cookie.delete('refresh_token','app/name');
```

It will definitely work.